# Not able to assign root privilege to my process again by using setuid(0) in the same boot cycle

Tags: linux, synchronization, setuid, capabilities

I have added the capability by using following cmd on terminal (alternative of setting CAP_SETUID  in drop-in file). Verified that setuid/seteuid is  working.

```
setcap  cap_sys_admin,cap_setuid+ep   /usr/bin/<processname>
```

Now I want to to set my process privileged as root --> sync() --> set to original privilege---> do some work --> set as root again--->sync()

while using setuid(),I have found out that we can set process as root  only one time in one boot cycle.
However it can be done by seteuid(), I have  tried that also , still not able to achieved the  desired result.

Can you please suggest  what I am missing or doing work.

```
int id = geteuid();
int r0= seteuid(0); // This will raise process to root mode     
sync();  //process can perform operation as root  user
seteuid(id);  //set process as non root  user
```

first time r0 is 0[successful], second time r0 is -1[error in seteuid(0)] . (In same boot cycle)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to be privileged to call `sync()`.  What's your rationale to do so?

Comment: Rather than trying to flip `seteuid`, run your unprivileged task in a subprocess

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not find an explicit explanation in the kernel documentation, just a hint in `man 2 setuid`:

> If the user is root or the program is set-user-ID-root, special care must be taken: setuid() checks the effective user ID of the caller and if it is the superuser, all process-related user ID's are set to uid. **After this has occurred, it is impossible for the program to regain root privileges.**

It would not make much sense to allow this to render this assertion invalid by adding capabilities. Why would a FSCAP program be more powerful than a SUID root program?

If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153895/7000756) on SO is correct, then your problem can be explained as:

> By default, capability sets are lost across an UID transition

The different behaviours of `setuid()` and `seteuid()` are intentional and cover different scenarios (switching back to root shall (not) be allowed).